# what are the different parts of xcode's memory viewer

Tags: xcode, memory

I'm starting to dig into c++ following along with some tutorials.

I hit a point where we started looking at the memory associated with particular variables and I pulled up xcode's memory viewer.

I know that the big block of ascii hex values in the middle are the values for my variables stored in memory, but I don't know what the rest of the sections are.

[image: screen shot of memory viewer]

I've been looking around online and in the xcode docs to try to find an explanation, but I'm not finding what these specific things are (it's a hard thing to find when there are no headings for the sections to search by).

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Address in decimal on the left, memory values represented in ASCII characters on the right.

Comment: Ah gotcha. Thanks for the explanation!